# Nested Transaction Scope for transactional Operation

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, transactions, transactionscope

I've got a doubt about transactionscope because I'd like to make a transactional operation where first I perform some CRUD operations (a transaction which inserts and updates some rows on the DataBase) and I got a result from the whole transaction (an XML).

After I got the XML I send the XML to a Web Service which my customer exposes to integrate my system with.

The point is, let's imagine that one day the WS that my customer exposes falls down due to a weekly or monthly support task that its IT Area perform, so everymoment I perform the whole thing It performs the DB operation but of course It will throw an exception at the moment that I try to call the WS.

After Searching on the Internet I started to think of Transaction Scope. My Data Access Method which is on my Data Access Layer already has a TransactionScope where I perform insert, update, delete, etc.

The following Code is what I'd like to try:

```
    public void ProcessSomething()
    {
        using (TransactionScope mainScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            FooDAL dl = new FooDAL();

            string message = dl.ProcessTransaction();

            WSClientFoo client = new WSClientFoo();

            client.SendTransactionMessage(message);

            mainScope.Complete();

        }
    }

public class FooDAL
{
    public string ProcessTransaction()
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions(){ IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted}))
        {
            ///Do Insert, Update, Delete and According to the Operation Generates a message

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return transactionMessage;
    }
}
```

The question is, is it correct to use TransactionScope to handle what I want to do ?

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

`TransactionScopeOption.Required` in your FooDAL.ProcessTransaction method means in fact: if there is a transaction available, reuse it in this scope; otherwise, create a new one.

So in short: yes, this is the correct way of doing this.

But be advised that if you don't call scope.Complete() in FooDAL.ProcessTransaction, a call to mainScope.Complete() will crash with a 'TransactionAbortedException' or something like that, which makes sense: if a nested scope decides that the transaction cannot be committed the outer scope should not be able to commit it.